# Formula for angle in triangle when two sides and the included angle are known

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

Given a triangle $ABC$ with edges $a$, $b$, and $c$ and corresponding angles
$\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Assume, the values of $a$, $b$ and $\gamma$ are given. Does there exist a direct theorem (like the law of cosines, the law of sines or the law of tangents) which describes the relationship between these parameters and $\alpha$?

Obviously, one can use the law of cosine to calculate $c$
and then apple the law of sine to solve the problem.
But does there exist a specific formula for the relationship which can be applied without a step in between? Maybe, someone could give me some advice. I have already read the entire article on Wikipedia about trigonometry. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is indirect about the sine and cosine rules?

Comment: @Allawonder starting with the assumption that only $a,b,$ and $\gamma$ are known, you can't directly use the Law of Sines (i.e. none of $\alpha, \beta$ or $c$ are **immediately** known).  The OP himself indicates that the triangle is completely solvable via the Law of Cosines, but that this approach takes *more than one step*.  In my opinion, the only way to compress the algorithm into one step is to **completely** solve the triangle for **generic** values of $a,b,\gamma$ and then simply **save** the **generic formula**.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. 
For future reference, you may take a look at 
[this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
to see how to format math on this site.

Comment: The Law of cosines tells us $$c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cdot \cos(\gamma)}$$ Therefore, the Law of Sines yields $$\alpha=\arcsin\left(\frac{a\cdot \sin(\gamma)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cdot \cos(\gamma)}}\right)$$

Comment: @Dr.Mathva: This will get wrong value for obtuse $\alpha$.

Answer (score 3):

As you already know by cosine rule we can find $c$ as
\begin{align} 
c&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\gamma}
.
\end{align}
However, it's not a good idea to use the sine rule to find $\alpha$,
since in general, $\alpha$ could be obtuse.
It's better to use known identity

\begin{align}
b&=a\cos\gamma+c\cos\alpha
\end{align}

to get the final expression for $\alpha$
in terms of $a,\ b$, and $\gamma$:

\begin{align}
\alpha&=\arccos\left(
\frac{b-a\cos\gamma}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\gamma}}
\right)
.
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) $c=a\cos \beta+b\cos \alpha$ is an under-rated identity! I find it v. useful - as you say it's often better to use cosine than sine - but I rarely see it in textbooks. Do you know if it even has a name? For anyone wondering about its applications, two quick examples. If $c$ is the hypotenuse of a right-angled triangle we immediately get $c=a(a/c)+b(b/c)$, proving Pythagoras' theorem. Or to prove the law of cosines, multiply by $c$ to get $c^2=ca\cos \beta+bc\cos \alpha$, similarly $a^2=ab\cos \gamma+ca\cos \beta$ and $b^2=bc\cos \alpha+ab\cos \gamma$ so eg $a^2+b^2-c^2=2ab\cos \gamma$

Comment: I've heard it said that when $a$ is close to $b$ and $\gamma$ is small, there's a numerical accuracy advantage to using the law of tangents instead of the law of cosines. For most people's purposes this might not be a big deal, but experimenting with a Casio pocket calculator I found putting $a=b=1$ and $\gamma=10^{-3}$ degrees in this formula gave $\alpha$ as `89.99950001` instead of the correct `89.9995`, and by $\gamma=10^{-5}$ we already get a `Math ERROR`. More details in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4871023/72968)

Comment: Follow-up to my earlier comment: $c = a \cos \beta + b \cos \alpha$ is called the **projection formula** , e.g. in Rusk, W. J. (1921). *Discussions: Some Formulas of Elementary Trigonometry*. The American Mathematical Monthly, 28(11/12), 443-446,  https://doi.org/10.2307/2972474 and using that as a search term produces a lot of hits in modern Indian geometry exam prep material.

Answer (score 1):

When you know two sides and the angle between them, the so-called "side-angle-side" case, older textbooks would recommend using the [law of tangents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents) to find the remaining angles,  if you don't want to bother finding the remaining side. I think that's what you mean by "directly" finding the other angles. This avoids having to use the law of cosines altogether: particularly useful before electronic calculators when you'd rather avoid calculating a square root, but even today the law of tangents can have better numerical performance (if $a$ and $b$ are similar and $\gamma$ is small then [applying the law of cosines can produce errors by catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents#Application)).

Suppose $a>b$ and so $\alpha>\beta$. How much of the length of $BC = a$ would you have to redistribute to $AC =b$ to make them the legs of an isosceles triangle with apex at $C$? Cut off the half-difference $\frac{1}{2}(a-b)$ from $a$ and give it to $b$, then the lengths would be equalised to their half-sum (i.e. mean) value $\frac{1}{2}(a+b)$. You may want to check my claims that $a - \frac{1}{2}(a-b) = \frac{1}{2}(a+b)$ and $b + \frac{1}{2}(a-b) = \frac{1}{2}(a+b)$. Note that if I told you the half-sum and half-difference, these relations allow you to reconstitute the original lengths as $a = \frac{1}{2}(a+b) + \frac{1}{2}(a-b)$ and $b = \frac{1}{2}(a+b) - \frac{1}{2}(a-b)$. **In general, given the half-sum and half-difference of any two quantities, the larger one was half-sum plus half-difference and the smaller one was half-sum subtract half-difference.** Now, consider the ratio of the half-sum over the half-difference,

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}(a-b)}{\frac{1}{2}(a+b)}$$

which shows *the proportionate length change needed to equalise $a$ and $b$, relative to their mean length*. This is a number between zero (already isosceles, no adjustment needed) and one (degenerate case where one length is zero and a full half of the other length must be donated to equalise them) that measures how asymmetric $\triangle ABC$ is when considered as a not-quite-isosceles triangle with apex $C$. Some textbooks cancel out the common factor of half in this fraction, others retain them because it gives the overall formula a more memorable symmetry.

Equalising the legs of the triangle would also equalise the base angles. Since the apex angle is still $\gamma$, the base angles still must sum to $\alpha + \beta$ for the angle sum of the triangle to work out. So the angles are *also* equalised to the half-sum $\frac{1}{2}(\alpha + \beta)$ and we must donate their half-difference $\frac{1}{2}(\alpha - \beta)$ from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ to achieve this. Again we can reconstitute $\alpha$ as the half-sum plus half-difference and $\beta$ as the half-sum subtract half-difference. **Importantly, if you know $\gamma$ then the angle sum of a triangle tells you what the angle sum $\alpha + \beta$ must be, so you can easily work out the half-sum $\frac{1}{2}(\alpha + \beta)$.** Finally, consider the ratio

$$\frac{\tan \frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\beta)}{\tan \frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta)}$$

which (since $\tan$ is an increasing function from zero to a right-angle, the range in which the angle half-sum and half-difference lie) must also be a number between zero and one, again describing how badly $\triangle ABC$ deviates from being isosceles with apex $C$.

The law of tangents just says these two measures of your triangle's asymmetry are equal.

$$\frac{\tan \frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\beta)}{\tan \frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta)} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}(a-b)}{\frac{1}{2}(a+b)}$$

In the SAS case where you know $a$, $b$ and $\gamma$, you can start by working out the angle half-sum $\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta)$ so the only remaining unknown is the angle half-difference $\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\beta)$. Then the law of tangents gives

$$\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\beta) = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{a-b}{a+b} \tan \frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta) \right)$$

where for ease of computation I didn't bother halving the sum and difference of the lengths. From the half-sum and half-difference, you can reconstitute $\alpha$ as half-sum plus half-difference and $\beta$ as half-sum subtract half-difference.

For an explicit formula in terms of $a$, $b$ and $\gamma$ only, let me write the angle sum of the triangle as $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi$ (I'm working in [radian measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), high schoolers may need to replace $\pi$ by $180^\circ$) so the half-sum is $\frac{1}{2}(\alpha + \beta) = \frac{1}{2}(\pi - \gamma)$ and

$$\alpha = \frac{\pi - \gamma}{2} + \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{a-b}{a+b} \tan \frac{\pi - \gamma}{2} \right)$$

$$\beta = \frac{\pi - \gamma}{2} - \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{a-b}{a+b} \tan \frac{\pi - \gamma}{2} \right)$$

Depending on taste, you may prefer to use the [complementary trig functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1227697/72968) to rewrite $\tan \frac{1}{2}(\pi - \gamma)$ as $\cot \frac{\gamma}{2}$.

Does this have any advantage compared to [@g.kov's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4006999/72968)?

$$\alpha = \arccos\left(
\frac{b-a\cos\gamma}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\gamma}}
\right)$$

Without doing a full error analysis, let's check the case where I said numerical error could be worse for the law of cosines than the law of tangents: $a$ similar to $b$ and $\gamma$ small. In fact I'll put $a=b=1$ so the triangle is exactly isosceles and we *should* get $\alpha$ as $\gamma/2$ less than a right angle. Working in degrees on my pocket Casio calculator, the cosine formula displays `89.99950001` when $\gamma=10^{-3}$ instead of the exact `89.9995`, and `89.9999501` when $\gamma=10^{-4}$ instead of the exact `89.99995`. For $\gamma=10^{-5}$ and below, attempting the calculation produces a `Math ERROR`. Note that the calculator stores additional digits beyond the ones it displays, used for rounding and to retain numerical accuracy in further calculations: subtracting the exact answer can reveal the error in these non-displayed digits. With the cosine formula there is already an error of magnitude $8.7 \times 10^{-11}$ when $\gamma = 0.1^\circ$. In contrast all the Casio's digits (both displayed and non-displayed) were exactly correct when using the tangent formula with $\gamma$ a small power of ten, until $\gamma = 10^{-11}$ degrees when a `Math ERROR` was produced. This was caused by the $\tan \left( \frac{180^\circ - \gamma}{2} \right)$ which the Casio cannot evaluate for $\gamma = 10^{-11}$.